# Google sheets; Compare data in 3 columns & rows and highlight cells if similar data

Tags: google-sheets

Right now I am tasked to compare similar data across 3 columns and its respective rows and then highlight them.

I was wondering whether if it is possible to format the spreadsheet so that the cells highlight on their own across their respective rows when similar data is entered into the cells.

I have attached an example in the [link provided](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C1hztz6EMAit3OeBxc1yoEloeAzRjWr04BtfmEdffJI/edit?usp=sharing) !

Comment: You should be able to do it with countifs - what have you tried so far? By the way, the link appears to have 5 columns?

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for getting back to me! I only want to formart the first 3 columns in this case. Sadly i do not know how to formart spreadsheets but i would like to learn how to do this. It’ll be great if you could show me the formula and explain how it works:) Would truly appreciate you sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK select the range you want to format then go to Format | Conditional format | Add new rule and choose the last option (Custom formula is...) under Format cells if...

Enter the following formula (adjusting range to how many rows and columns you have in your data)

```
=countifs($A$2:$A$18,$A2,$B$2:$B$18,$B2,$C$2:$C$18,$C2)>1
```

and choose the fill colour that you want.

The formula counts how many rows there are whose first three columns match the first three columns of the current row. If the result is greater than one, there is a duplicate and the current row should be formatted.

[image]